# Determine if two inputs are within 10 integers of one another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've encountered a problem where I need to find out whether or not two inputs are withing 10 integers of one another however I need the values to be the result of different inputs like so:

```
value_1 = int(input("Value 1:  "))
value_2 = int(input("Value 2:  "))
```

However the values may not be identical, this is how far I've come right not however it doesn't work.

```
val_1 = float(input("Skriv in valfritt värde:   "))
val_2 = float(input("Skriv in valfritt värde:   "))

if val_1 == val_2:
    print("Grattis!")

elif (val_1 - val_2 <= 10) and (val_1 != val_2):
    print("Close but no cigar!")

else:
    print("Not even close!")
```

(Some of the words the code outputs is written in Swedish.)

However the code works fine as long as `val_1` is more than `val_2`, I'm not sure how to fix it so when `val_2` is more than `val_1` it still works.

i.e. Now when I input 3.24 as `val_1` and `123.6` as `val_2`, I still get `Close but no cigar!` even though I want to get `Not even close`.

I've tried adding another and statement with the opposite symbol (`>= 10` instead of `<= 10`) but it doesn't work.

Code written in python 3.8,

Comment: Test `if abs(val_1 - val_2) <= 10: `

Comment: [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)

Comment: that worked! Thanks for the help! I use float if the input is a decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `abs` function to get the magnitude of the difference:

```
if val_1 == val_2:
    print("Grattis!")
elif abs(val_1 - val_2) <= 10:
    print("Close but no cigar!")
else:
    print("Not even close!")
```

This is logically the same as:

```
if val_1 == val_2:
    print("Grattis!")
elif -10 <= val_1 - val_2 <= 10:
    print("Close but no cigar!")
else:
    print("Not even close!")
```

but using `abs` is clearer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This is more algebra than Python, but ...

You have two basic choices.  You mentioned a compound check, but used the wrong conjunction:

```
elif (val_1 - val_2 <= 10 or val_2 - val_1 <= 10) ...
```

Perhaps easier is to use the absolute value function:

```
elif (abs(val_1 - val_2) <= 10) ...
```

You can further simplify this one to include your check against equality:

```
elif (0 < abs(val_1 - val_2) <= 10):
    print("Close but no cigar!")
```

Comment: Also `if -10 <= val_1 - val_2 <= 10`

Comment: That last part doesn't make much sense. If they're equal, they'd go into the `if`-branch and not consider the `elif`.